# what's the effective way of managing session data in java clustering environment?

Tags: java, session, failovercluster

suppose we have an internet web site with high visits, say, 10M pv per day,

say,

1. session sticky can not handle failover in a nice way, the users will be impacted;
2. session replication may cause too much overhead,
3. use some clustered cache server for storing actual session data and only do session replication for things like key (say, useid)?

I once asked someone in ebay and they say they use in memory mysql clustering for this.
any good ways/best practice?

Comment: A MySQL database can handle 100+ updates/queries per second.  What is the PV rate for the busiest second of the day?

Comment: This is not [tag:cluster-analysis]. Please tag with more care.

Comment: @PeterLawrey  i do not have business rate data yet, we assume it should have 10 million pv a day

Comment: So do you mean about 12 per second?

Comment: @PeterLawrey well, since it's surely not mean distribution, i do not have the data yet, but i'd expect it should at least handle 1000 dynamic request per second if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> well, since it's surely not mean distribution, i do not have the data yet, but i'd expect it should at least handle 1000 dynamic request per second if possible

It is possible to have bursts of this much activity, which is why I asked.  The solution is different depending on what you believe the burst to be.  You can support 1K updates per second, with MySQL provided you have a fast disk (disk controller cached or SSD)

BTW: I have a library for a database which supports 200K - 20M updates per second on commodity hardware, but its not as easy to use, so you really need to need it. ;)

Comment: thx very much. looks like in memory mysql will be mostly considered.

Comment: Basically because its simple to use/understand. I would create an abstraction layer so you can replace the database in the future, should you need to.

Answer (score 0):

In memory cluster is best option, see

http://www.mysql.com/products/cluster/features.html

Comment: thx for mention this again, did anyone compare this against terracotta solution above?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Terracotta Websessions

- http://terracotta.org/
- http://terracotta.org/products/web-sessions

Comment: did anyone compare this against in memory mysql cluster?